# Create view only for specific editor in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

How can I show view when specific editor is selected and hide it when another is selected? I was looking for this in extension points but I found nothing :(
Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register [IPartListener](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/IPartListener.html) with [IPartService](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/IPartListener.html) and then do appropriate things in partActivated, partBroughtToTop, etc. methods.
Make sure that the part is the editor you want:

```
public void partActivated(IWorkbenchPart part) {
  if (part instanceof MySuperEditor) {
    part.getSite().getPage().showView(MySuperView.ID);
  }
}
```

and so on.
Let me know if that helps.

Comment: It's working but I don't know where is good place for creating this listener. What do you think about activator? In methods start and stop? I want add this listener using method PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getPartService().addPartListener(listener);

Comment: @John getActiveWorkbenchWindow() approach will only work if you only have one Eclipse window open at the time. You need to get all of the windows and register the listener with each. Also, you'll need another IWindowListener to make sure you add the part listener to newly created windows and remove the ones registered for windows being closed. I'm not sure about the best practices. In my plugin I just had a method which was invoked from plugin strartup which would wait for Workbench creation and window initilization to complete and then register all of the listeners.